# Is there anyway to disambiguate constructor selection?

Tags: c++

I have a small code like this:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout << "ctor\n";
    }

    A(int i = 5) {
        std::cout << "ctor -> v\n";
    }

    virtual ~A() {
        std::cout << "dtor\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
}
```

It is is obvious that this code won't compile because `A`'s constructor is ambiguous. I wonder if there is anyway to disambiguate this code by manually selecting which constructor to call. I don't want to pass default value in order to disambiguate function call (which is a obvious approach). I just want to know if there is any other way or not.

Comment: @JeJo I'm just playing with code for better understanding C++. You normally can merge both constructors into one, but my question is if it is possible differentiate between these two.

Comment: Actually a good question but very deep. I was wandering whether you can actually create a call in C++ to the unmangled constructor signature somehow (because this would not be ambiguous) but even if possible, this would be very unportable code then

Comment: @Samuel yea, because these 2 are overloaded with 2 different mangeling, I thought maybe there is a approach to select between them. It seems there are ways to do so for non-constructor situations by casting into specific declaration, but not sure about constructor.

Comment: Voting to reopen as the duplicate is tagged c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing the constructor definitions there is no way in standard C++ to disambiguate the call.

Your options for clearing the ambiguity are to either remove the default argument, or to add a "dummy" tag argument to the first constructor.

```
constexpr struct default_tag_t{} default_tag{};
///
A(default_tag_t) {
    std::cout << "ctor\n";
}
```

Which makes the first constructor uniquely callable with

```
A a(default_tag);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I can see (if you *really* need both constructors) is to remove the default value of the argument in the second constructor and make the 'default' constructor call that:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A() : A(5) {
        std::cout << "ctor\n";
    }

    A(int i) {
        std::cout << "ctor -> v\n";
    }

    virtual ~A() {
        std::cout << "dtor\n";
    }
};
```

But then, for the default ('empty') instatiation, the body code for *both* constructors will execute.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think it is not possible. I was looking into getting to call the mangled name but I was not able to generate those mangled names. For this you have to expose the class to the binary interface by adding a `__declspec(dllexport)` and after you do this, even compiling the class is no longer possible (regardless of calling any ctor):

```
#include <iostream>
class __declspec(dllexport)  A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout << "ctor\n";
    }

    A(int i = 5) {
        std::cout << "ctor -> v\n";
    }

    virtual ~A() {
        std::cout << "dtor\n";
    }
};

int main() {
   // A a;
}
```

Output was

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplicationMangled, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConsoleApplicationMangled.cpp
1>e:\temp\ConsoleApplicationMangled\ConsoleApplicationMangled\ConsoleApplicationMangled.cpp(5,30): error C2668: 'A::A': ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>e:\temp\ConsoleApplicationMangled\ConsoleApplicationMangled\ConsoleApplicationMangled.cpp(11,5): message : could be 'A::A(int)'
1>e:\temp\ConsoleApplicationMangled\ConsoleApplicationMangled\ConsoleApplicationMangled.cpp(7,5): message : or       'A::A(void)'
1>e:\temp\ConsoleApplicationMangled\ConsoleApplicationMangled\ConsoleApplicationMangled.cpp(18,2): message : while trying to match the argument list '()'
1>e:\temp\ConsoleApplicationMangled\ConsoleApplicationMangled\ConsoleApplicationMangled.cpp(18,2): message : This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'void A::__dflt_ctor_closure(void)'
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplicationMangled.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```